# Child processes can't finish because parent finished first

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, exec

From what I understand, after fork(), if the parent does not call wait() and finishes before its children, the children should still be able to go on and finish what they are doing. (because they get picked up by init).
However, in my code, the children can't finish what they are doing unless the parent calls wait() or sleep() a certain amount of time which basically is waiting for them to finish.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t pid;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 3) {
      ++i;
      switch (pid = fork()) {
        case -1: {
            printf("couldn't fork\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        case 0: {
            execv(...) // The forked child goes off to execute some other 
                       // program.
                       // The other program prints a line to console every 
                       // 2 seconds. It prints 3 lines altogether.

            perror("couldn't execv\n");
            exit(0);
        }
      }
    }
             // while should spawn 3 children and print 9 lines.
   sleep(10) // If I sleep here the 9 lines will show.
             // Or if I wait 3 times
             //int j = 0;
            // while (j < 3) {
            // ++j; wait(NULL);
             // }

// But if I don't wait or sleep, only 3 lines (the first line of each 
// childprocess is printed)
}
```

This is the other program executed by execv

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
printf("a\n");
sleep(2);
printf("b\n");
sleep(2);
printf("c\n");
sleep(2);
return 0;
}
```

If I don't sleep() or wait(), the output is

```
a
a
a
```

If I sleep() or wait(), the correct output is displayed.

```
a
a
a
b
b
b
c
c
c
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Daniel if I don't sleep() or wait(), shouldn't the output still be 9 lines?

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `exit(0);`  In general, a return/exit value of 0 indicates SUCCESS.  However, those statements are in error paths, so the (expected) statement is: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Where `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are defined in `stdlib.h`

Comment: OT: in the child process, this statement: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {` will cause the compiler to output two warning messages about unused parameters.  When the parameters to `main()` are not going to be used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks, ok, I'll change that. But what about the problem I'm describing?

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("couldn't fork\n");`  1) Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2) when the error indication is from a C library function, then should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest: `perror( "fork failed");`  As this outputs your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: I don't actually experience the problem you're describing.  It might be shell related, though I've tried it in both bash and zsh and have the same results: without the sleep, my shell presents its prompt before the first 'a' prints out, but the three 'a's, 'b's, and 'c's all print out fine after that.

Comment: how are you running the program?